# Como utilizar métodos de redirecionamento com as Servlets Java

Tags: java, jsp, redirecionamento, servlet, request

Olá, tenho uma página **ordem_servico.jsp** com um formulário que quando submetido vai para a **ServletInsertOrdemServico** que insere os dados do formulário no banco de dados.
Estou tentando fazer com que quando os dados forem inseridos, o browser retorne para a página **ordem_servico.jsp** e apresente um **alert** do javascript dizendo que a ordem foi inserida com sucesso, meu código está assim:

```
    RequestDispatcher rd;
    if( dao.cadastrarOS(os) ) {
        rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/paginas/ordem_servico.jsp");
        rd.include(request, response);
        out.print(
            "<script type=\"text/javascript\">"
                +"alert(\“Ordem inserida com sucesso!\”);"+
            "</script>"
        );
    }
```

Esse código está fazendo exatamente o que eu quero, porém esse **getRequestDispatcher()** redireciona para http://localhost:8080/ServletInsertOrdemServico , e eu não consigo mais acessar nenhum link interno da página, pois os links para outras páginas obviamente estão fora do contexto da Servlet, e assim o glassfish retorna o erro 404.

Ao invés de usar o getRequestDispatcher(), eu já tentei usar o **response.sendRedirect("paginas/ordem_servico.jsp")**, nesse caso eu consigo inserir os dados e acessar os links internos, porém o alert do javascript **não** é apresentado.

Alguém que já passou por essa situação teria alguma sugestão?

Agradeço a todos!

Comment: Na verdade com o código acima ele mostra o alert, o problema é que eu não consigo acessar links internos, pois o getRequestDispatcher redireciona para a servlet e não para o jsp, e se eu usar o response.sendRedirect, ele redireciona para o jsp, mas não exibe o alert, obrigado renan!

Comment: Também não, ele redireciona para a servlet do mesmo jeito

Comment: Esse código está dentro do JSP ou do Servlet?

Answer (score 1):

Embora sua abordagem esteja funcionando, elá está muito fora dos padrões.
Uma forma alternativa e mais interessante seria fixar o `alert` em sua página `JSP` e só exibi-lo se passar na condição de que os dados foram inseridos com sucesso.

Em seu **JSP**, ficaria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
<script>

document.onload = function() {

    if(${sessionScope.resultado} == "sucesso"){
        alert("Ordem inserida com sucesso!");
    }

};

</script>
```

Agora, em seu **Servlet**, o código seria mais ou menos assim:

```
if(dao.cadastrarOS(os)) {
    request.getSession().setAttribute("resultado", "sucesso");
    response.sendRedirect("/paginas/ordem_servico.jsp");
}
```

**ENTENDENDO O POR QUE O SESSION**

O que seria comum utilizar é o `request.setAttribute()`, no entanto, você não terá acesso ao `request` quando se utiliza e `sendRedirect()` pelo response. Logo você terá que utilizar o `session` já que ele é persistente entre diversas requisições.

*Não se esqueça de remover o atributo "resultado" em `session` para reutiliza-lo para outros propositos.*